# The order of a perfect in shuffle is the order of a perfect out shuffle with two more cards proof

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm checking out [this paper](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/papers/83_05_shuffles.pdf).

And in Lemma 1 I thoroughly understand the proof except for the first line which states: "The order of an in shuffle is the order of an out shuffle with a deck containing 2 more cards, ... "

I don't follow this statement can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An out shuffle leaves the top card on the top and the bottom card on the bottom.  If you take an $n$ card deck and perform an out shuffle, you get the same permutation as if you take the top and bottom cards off, perform an in shuffle on the remaining $n-2$ cards, and restore the top and bottom cards.  The number of shuffles to restore the original state is the same in both cases.